# Brackets in function name in rxjs

Tags: rxjs

On this page,

http://reactivex.io/rxjs/file/es6/Subscriber.js.html

why is the function below have brackets? Does it have any meaning?

```
[rxSubscriberSymbol]() { return this; }
```

Answer (score 3):

Square brackets around a method name indicate this is a computed property name, see the docs on MDN [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names)